# What's a clean way to verify a few objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, validation, object

I'm trying to find an efficient way to check if an array contains objects that I expect. In the example I have below, I'm expecting to have objects in `fruit` that have `type` = `apple, banana, and orange`. If `banana` is missing for example, then it should return `false`.

**Here is a very elementary solution:**

```
const fruit = [
  {'type': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'quantity': 10},
  {'type': 'banana', 'color': 'yellow', 'quantity': 9},
  {'type': 'orange', 'color': 'orange', 'quantity': 3}
  ];

let fruitsToCheck = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];
let fruitsThatExist = [];

fruit.forEach( fruit => {
  fruitsThatExist.push(fruit.type);
});

fruitsToCheck = fruitsToCheck.sort().toString();
fruitsThatExist = fruitsThatExist.sort().toString();

const allExist = fruitsToCheck === fruitsThatExist;
```

The solution I have works but it is not efficient. What is a better approach to this problem?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - this question belongs here

Answer (score 0):

Check out [array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const allExist = fruitsToCheck.every(type =>
  fruit.some(fruit => fruit.type === type)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fruits = [
  {'type': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'quantity': 10},
  {'type': 'banana', 'color': 'yellow', 'quantity': 9},
  {'type': 'orange', 'color': 'orange', 'quantity': 3}
  ];
  
 console.log(fruits.find(fruit => fruit.type === 'apple' || fruit.type === 'banana' || fruit.type === 'orange') !== undefined)
```

if you need to check if all fruits apple, banana and orange presents

```js
const fruits = [
      {'type': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'quantity': 10},
      {'type': 'banana', 'color': 'yellow', 'quantity': 9},
      {'type': 'orange', 'color': 'orange', 'quantity': 3}
      ];
      
const map = {
  'apple': 0,
  'banana': 0,
  'orange': 0
}
     
console.log(fruits.reduce((sum, fruit) => sum + (map[fruit.type] === 0 ? ++map[fruit.type] : 0), 0) === 3)
```

Comment: Doesn't this just find one object? I don't think it checks for the presence of all three.

Comment: it will find the first object has type apple, banana or orange, and return immediately.

Comment: Add an example for checking all fruit types exist

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the types in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check with [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) as callback for [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const
    fruit = [{ type: 'apple', color: 'red', quantity: 10 }, { type: 'banana', color: 'yellow', quantity: 9 }, { type: 'orange', color: 'orange', quantity: 3 }],
    fruitsToCheck = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
    allExist = fruitsToCheck.every(
        Set.prototype.has,                     // callback
        new Set(fruit.map(({ type }) => type)) // thisArg
    );

console.log(allExist);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `every` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value. [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

The `some` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value. [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const fruit = [
  {'type': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'quantity': 10},
  {'type': 'banana', 'color': 'yellow', 'quantity': 9},
  {'type': 'orange', 'color': 'orange', 'quantity': 3}
];

let fruitsToCheck = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];

// solution - 1 
const allExist = fruitsToCheck.every(t => fruit.some(f => f.type === t));

// soution - 2
const allExist = fruitsToCheck.every(f => fruit.map(fr => fr.type).includes(f))

// soution - 3 
const allExist = [...new Set(fruit.map(f => f.type))].length === fruitsToCheck.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function to check if every type from the fruit object is [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on your fruits to check array.

```js
const fruit = [
  {'type': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'quantity': 10},
  {'type': 'banana', 'color': 'yellow', 'quantity': 9},
  {'type': 'orange', 'color': 'orange', 'quantity': 3}
  ];
  
const fruitsToCheck = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];

const allExist = fruit.every(({type})=> fruitsToCheck.includes(type))

console.log(allExist);
```